# Handling invalid MVC parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In our MVC application we have a route defined as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewUser", "ViewUser/{userId}", new { controller = "general", action = "viewuser", userId = 0 });
```

userId is defined as an non-nullable type int, with a default value of 0.  However occasionally, we find that the google ad bot will for some unknown reason call the page as /ViewUser/phptest.php.  This results in an 500 error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'userId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'
```

For the now, if we ignore the fact that google is trying to crawl an invalid url, is there anyway to force a 404 as opposed to the 500 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that I can think of is completely removing the default route and specifying route constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "ViewUser", 
   "ViewUser/{userId}", 
   new { controller = "general", action = "viewuser", userId = @"\d+" });
```

This way the route will be used only when `userId` satisfies the constraint (number in this case). And since you won't have a default route (or any other route that matches the request) you should get a 404 as requested.

The downside is that you will have to explicitly specify routes for all the actions(either in Route.config or by using route attributes)

Comment: You can do this `{userId:int}` also

Comment: If I am not mistaken this option was added only in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: Yes in version 5. Indeed.